# how to prepare subquery in zend framework

Tags: subquery, zend-db

I want to prepare a subquery like this in zend framework:

```
select * from dept_view
where
(
   (select sum(sal) from emp where emp_id IN (10,11))
   &
   dept_sal
)
```

any ideas ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$subSelect = $db->select();
$subSelect->from('emp', array('SUM(sal)'))
  ->where('emp_id IN (?)', array(10,11));

$select = $db->select();
$select->from('dept_view')
 ->where($subSelect);
```